# specification-arg-resolver - URL operators

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

Looking at the sample code from specification-argument-resolver,

```java
@Controller
  public class SampleController {
    
    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    
    @RequestMapping("/find")
    public List<Customer> findByRegistrationDate(
            @And({
                @Spec(path = "name", params = "name", spec = Equal.class),
                @Spec(path = "registrationDate", params = "registrationDate", spec = GreaterThanOrEqual.class)
            }) Specification<Customer> spec) {
        return customerRepository.findAll(spec);
    }
  }
  
  @Entity
  public class Customer {
    String name;
    Date registrationDate;
  }
```

Looking at the sample code from [specification-argument-resolver](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver#or), the sample request looks like below:

```java
GET /find?name=John&registrationDate=2020-06-19
```

Is there a way for the query params to reflect the actual operator.

Example: registrationDate>=2020-06-19 instead of just =

I am looking for a hybrid between RSQL and specification-argument-resolver.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and more logical) to have the parameter name actually reflect what is asked for instead? E.g. `registeredAfter` or `registeredAfterInclusive`.

Answer (score 0):

You may just use this library: https://github.com/turkraft/spring-filter

It will let you run search queries such as:

> */search?filter=* **average**(ratings) **>** 4.5 **and** brand.name **in** ('audi', 'land rover') **and** (year **>** 2018 **or** km **<** 50000) and color **:** 'white' **and** accidents **is empty**

It supports dates too, and manages very well the n+1 query problem.